# How to make custom payment to a customer

Tags: stripe-payments

I am looking for a way to make payment to a customer like a business do.
for eg. a business will ask you to fill the form with bank name, acoount number IFSC code etc.
so customer can receive a payment.

I have user who is having a digital wallet with some amount.
I want to transfer the amount to user's provided bank account on the request.

I saw stripe documentation but I am not sure if stripe support custom payment.

Stripe provides refund as per below method where I have to provide charge id string
and because of charge id stripe will refund only the amount which was charged earlier and this is linked to particular charge only.

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('your_stripe_key');

const refund = await stripe.refunds.create({
  charge: 'charge_id_string',
  amount: 100,
});
```

I want to make custom payment/refund so I can transfer users wallet available balance to bank account.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use Refund because you can only create a refund based on an existing charge.

You should probably look at [Transfer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/create), which allows you to send funds from your Stripe account to a connected account. In your use case, you should create a connected account for your customer so that you can transfer refunds to your customer and eventually [payout](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payouts/create) to their bank account.

Visit [here](https://stripe.com/en-gb-sg/connect) to learn more about Stripe Connect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Qichuan. I have created two accounts one is custom and one is express. but both the accounts status shows restricted, also I have to register customer with bank account details but unable to find a way.

Comment: The account status remains restricted until you have provided the necessary information for verification. See https://stripe.com/docs/connect/required-verification-information for more info.

Comment: I made both the account active but I think stripe do not support transfers to non connected users eg. if user not registered with your connect account then transfer will not happen and you will end up with an error and I dont want to force user to register as a my connect user to just withdraw balance.

Comment: I asked stripe team and got the response that stripe currently do not support this, they may support in future.